# Using makecert for Development SSL

Tags: iis, ssl, makecert

Here's my situation:

I'm trying to create a SSL certificate that will be installed on all developer's machine's, along with two internal servers (everything is non-production).

What do I need to do to create a certificate that can be installed in all of these places?

Right now I've got something along these lines, using the makecert application in Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=MySite.com Dev" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2033 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss Root -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 mycert.cer
```

However, I'm not sure as to how to place this .cer file on the other computers, and when I install it on my local machine IIS, everytime I visit a page via https:, I get the security prompt (even after I've installed the certificate).  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Here are my scripts for doing this:

#### Create Certificate Authority

Create a self-signed certificate (-r), with an exportable private key (-pe), using SHA1 (-r), for signing (-sky signature).
The private key is written to a file (-sv).

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=My Root Authority" -ss CA -sr CurrentUser ^
         -a sha1 -sky signature -cy authority -sv CA.pvk CA.cer
```

(^= allow batch command-line to wrap line)

#### Create Server Certificate

Create a server certificate, with an exportable private key (-pe), using SHA1 (-a) for key exchange (-sky exchange).
It can be used as an SSL server certificate (-eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1).
The issuing certificate is in a file (-ic), as is the key (-iv).
Use a particular crypto provider (-sp, -sy).

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=fqdn.of.server" -a sha1 -sky Exchange ^
         -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ic CA.cer -iv CA.pvk ^
         -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" ^
         -sy 12 -sv server.pvk server.cer

pvk2pfx -pvk server.pvk -spc server.cer -pfx server.pfx
```

You then use the .PFX file in your server app (or install it in IIS). Note that, by default, **`pvk2pfx` doesn't apply a password to the output PFX file**. You need to use the `-po` switch for that.

To make all of your client machines trust it, install **CA.cer** in their certificate stores (in the Trusted Root Authorities store). If you're on a domain, you can use Windows Group Policy to do this globally. If not, you can use the **certmgr.msc** MMC snapin, or the **certutil** command-line utility:

```
certutil -user -addstore Root CA.cer
```

To programmatically install the certificate in IIS 6.0, look at [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=313624). For IIS 7.0, I don't know.

Comment: Here's where I'm stuck: How do you install the .PFX file in IIS?

Comment: I should qualify that:  I can get it to work if I go into the certificate snap-in and import it to the personal folder... but is there a way to do that without going through that process?  when I just double click on it and try that, it doesn't actually put the certificate in the folder

Comment: I'm following these steps and am able to create the pfx file however when I try to import the pfx file into IIS7 it says "The specified network password is not correct." Do you know how I can get it to import?  Thanks

Comment: Followup I just didn't enter anything for password and it imported it.

Comment: @dscoduc nice tool, for Win7 it needs masty's argument (-cy authority)

Comment: **For IIS7** this as easy as going to the IIS MMC -> server certificates -> right click -> create self signed certificate. Then add it to your site bindings.

Comment: This is by far the most complete answer I have ever seen. Definitely a +1.

Comment: For creating the server certificate I think you want to use the `-sk "somename"` parameter otherwise you'll end up with a blank name for the cert which looks strange in the cert store.

Comment: Even with my answer, above, I generally use PowerShell + BouncyCastle these days. It's more flexible than makecert. I should blog something about it....

Comment: Under Visual Studio 2010 command window, I ran your 2nd script I could get pvk file but not the cer file. If I remove `-ic CA.cer -iv CA.pvk` I got both. Any reason?

Comment: PowerShell + BouncyCastle: https://blog.differentpla.net/b/2013/31/17/how-do-i-use-bouncy-castle-from-powershell- and https://github.com/rlipscombe/PSBouncyCastle

Comment: Thanks heaps for this answer. It's the only one of several I have read that works. +1 I had to use the -po argument to set a password, without that the cer would not import into IIS.

Comment: +1 for a great answer.  Helped me fix my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows. I found that I needed to install BOTH pfx's in IIS.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12):

You should add `-cy authority` to the switches when creating the cert authority, otherwise some cert stores won't see it as a proper CA.