# How to get a x.509 certificate on windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, certificate, x509

In order to connect to a web service, I need a X.509 certificate.

With this certificate I then need to send a public key to the customer support of this web service.

I am really clueless on how to generate this certificate. I had a look at a few website explaining what is X.509, but I did not find something helpful.

Basically I would like to know:

- How can I generate a certificate ?
- How to get a public key from that certificate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496658/50079). It involves using the `makecert` tool, which is available on Windows systems.

For more information on what makecert can do and how to do it, see [this guide](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development) and the [makecert documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, I think the short answer is that you can do it with something like [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/). More info [here](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-self). I think there is also some other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=openssl+(509+OR+x509)+certificate) on SO that might help.

Try a command like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout your_private_key.pem -out your_cert.pem -nodes -config openssl.cfg -subj <Not sure what you'd put here> -days 365
```

That should generate your_private_key.pem, your private key, and your_cert, your certificate. You'd need to do some research as to what to enter for "subj", I know it needs to be in a specific format. I think you can just send customer support that certificate and they can retrieve the public key, or rather, maybe that certificate IS the public key. I'm not exactly an expert on this, but this should put you on the right track.

EDIT: Either run that command in the \bin directory of wherever you install OpenSSL, or change the value of "-config" to point to the right location of "openssl.cf", which is under \bin.

Comment: I get this error `No such file or directory:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:163:fopen('openssl.cfg','rb')`, that's weird probably I did not installed ssl correctly. Anyway, I've heard that windows XP had a "Web Certificate Wizard" (though I could not find it), isn't it easier to use ?

Comment: Try changing the path of -config to point to openssl.cfg (wherever you installed openssl). Sorry, I have never use the Web Certificate Wizard. I've only ever used openssl and it was only once, but it was for the exact case that you are using it for, so I thought I would chyme in.