# SSL certificate generation

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate

I am working on C# project where tcp transmition between server and client is made using SSL. I created certificate file with makecert program, but it works only on computer where it was generated (although I have installed .cer file). I am almost sure, that the problem lies in parameters which I put into command, but I checked many combinations and none (despit following) worked

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=This is my certificate" -ss my -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 ca.cer
```

.cer file is used only for ciphering transmition. I don't use PKI. Furthermore using SSL is "dead requirement" - it must be used, just for be used. Any security issues shouldn't be considered.

If anyone should answer me, how to create certificate, that will be able to be used by *X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile* method I would be delighted.

Comment: Do you need SSH or SSL? These are two different protocols.

Comment: Currently I am using System.Net.Security.SslStream class and it's AuthenticateAsServer(X509Certificate) method

Comment: When you say 'I have installed .cer file' -- where to? You need to install it to the CA store, otherwise it won't be trusted by the other machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using makecert for Development SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496658/using-makecert-for-development-ssl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control all of the machines that will use these certificates, you can create a CA that's trusted by all of the machines, and then issue certificates based on that.

Here are my batch files. The first one creates the CA certificate:

```
:// Create a self-signed certificate (-r),
:// with an exportable private key (-pe),
:// using SHA1 (-r), for signing (-sky signature).
:// The private key is written to a file (-sv).
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=My Root Authority" -ss CA ^
    -sr CurrentUser -a sha1 -sky signature -cy authority ^
    -sv CA.pvk CA.cer
```

Import the .CER file into the CA certificate store on those machines that must connect to the server (they must trust the CA):

```
:// Import that certificate into the
:// "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store.
certutil -user -addstore Root CA.cer
```

This one creates a server certificate:

```
:// Create a server certificate, with an exportable private key (-pe),
:// using SHA1 (-r) for key exchange (-sky exchange).
:// It can be used as an SSL server certificate (-eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1).
:// The issuing certificate is in a file (-ic), as is the key (-iv).
:// Use a particular crypto provider (-sp, -sy).
makecert -pe -n "CN=server.example.com" -a sha1 ^
    -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
    -ic CA.cer -iv CA.pvk ^
    -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 ^
    -sv server.pvk server.cer
pvk2pfx -pvk server.pvk -spc server.cer -pfx server.pfx
```

Install the .pfx file, and then get the C# server code to use it. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Roger I found your blog and managed to get it working and put a wrapper around it so it's easy to use and I also managed to set the friendly-Name on the certificates

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class SSLCertificateCreator
{
    public static string RunDosCommand(string Cmd, string Arguments)
    {//Executes a Dos command in the current directory and then returns the result
        string TestMessageText = "";
        string filePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = filePath + "\\" + Cmd,
            Arguments = Arguments + " ",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false
        };
        try
        {
            using (Process p = Process.Start(pi))
            {
                p.WaitForExit();
                TestMessageText = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                return TestMessageText;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            return "ERROR :" +Ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public static bool MakeCACertificate(string RootCertificateName, string FriendlyName)
    {//Make a CA certificate but only if we don't already have one and then sets the friendly name
        if (FindCertificate("Root", RootCertificateName, OpenFlags.ReadOnly) != null) return false; //We already have this root certificate
        string Arguments="-pe -n \"CN=" + RootCertificateName + "\" -ss Root -sr CurrentUser -a sha1 -sky signature -r \"" + RootCertificateName + ".cer\" -m 12";
        string Result=RunDosCommand("makecert", Arguments);
        X509Certificate2 Cert = FindCertificate("Root", RootCertificateName, OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        if (Cert == null || !Result.ToLower().StartsWith("succeeded")) return false;
        Cert.FriendlyName = FriendlyName;
        return true;
    }


    public static bool MakeSignedCertificate(string RootCertificateName, string CertificateName, string FriendlyName)
    {//Makes a signed certificate but only if we have the root certificate and then sets the friendly name
        if (FindCertificate("Root", RootCertificateName, OpenFlags.ReadOnly) == null) return false; //We must have a valid root-certificate first
        if (FindCertificate("my",CertificateName, OpenFlags.ReadOnly)!=null) return false;//Nope we alrady have this signed certificate
        string Arguments = "-pe -n \"CN=" + CertificateName + "\" -ss my -sr CurrentUser -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -in \"" + RootCertificateName + "\" -is Root -ir CurrentUser -sp \"Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider\" -sy 12 \"" + CertificateName + ".cer\" -m 12";
        string Result = RunDosCommand("makecert", Arguments);
        X509Certificate2 Cert = FindCertificate("my", CertificateName, OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        if (Cert==null || !Result.ToLower().StartsWith("succeeded")) return false;
        Cert.FriendlyName = FriendlyName;
        return true;
    }

    private static X509Certificate2 FindCertificate(string Store, string Name, OpenFlags Mode)
    {//Look to see if we can find the certificate store
        X509Store store = new X509Store(Store,StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(Mode);
        foreach (X509Certificate2 Cert in store.Certificates)
        {
            if (Cert.Subject.ToLower() =="cn="+ Name.ToLower()) 
                return Cert;//Yep found it
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Sample useage

SSLCertificateCreator.MakeCACertificate("DavesRoot","Nice Name");
            SSLCertificateCreator.MakeSignedCertificate("DavesRoot", "Daves Signed Certificate5","Nice Name");

makecert.exe needs to be in the Bin/Release or Debug directory for the code to work and this code has only ever been tested on Windows-8

Comment: If you're generating certificates in C#, then you should look at Bouncy Castle. I have a series of blog posts on the topic: http://blog.differentpla.net/tag/bouncy-castle

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a valid certificate. The one generated by makecert command is only for testing and wont work on other systems.

Comment: but how should I achieve this:) Program is just for academic use, so I would not like to collaborate with CA. How could I generate valid certificate, which could be used on two, different machines?

Comment: It will if you install it correctly. It should still only be used for testing or internal purposes.

Comment: The certificate needs to be generated from a valid provider like verisign, etc. You need to pay for that. 
Kindly mark it as answered if this helped you