# Certificate creation failed

Tags: .net, windows, networking, ssl

I am using the following commands to create a certificate:

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=Client" -pe -ss my -sr LocalMachine -sky exchange -in "Blue Yonder Airlines Root CA" -is my -ir LocalMachine Client.cer


certutil -privatekey -exportpfx -p 1 "Client" Client.pfx > NUL
```

However, I am getting an error message:

**Error: There is no matching certificate in the issuer's my cert store
Failed**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this guide below.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/applisec/archive/2008/04/08/creating-x-509-certificates-using-makecert-exe.aspx

Also you could refer to this question as well.

[Using makecert for Development SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496658/using-makecert-for-development-ssl)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the certificate in the Trusted Root Certificate Authority (or that it is trusted via chain trust), and that you have the certificate (with its private key) in the Personal store.  Both locations are in the Local Computer too and not your Personal store.

Also, if you have more than one copy of the issuer cert in your Local Computer's Trusted Root Certificate Authority or its Personal store, you will get this or a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to to run the command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Makecert can't find "Blue Yonder Airlines Root CA" in the Personal store of Local Computer scope

```
-in "Blue Yonder Airlines Root CA" -is my -ir LocalMachine
```

The cert must exist there with the CN=**Blue Yonder Airlines Root CA**.
Also the cert "Blue Yonder Airlines Root CA" might need to be in the Trusted Root.

Answer (score 0):

Hey If you open the Certificates through certsmgr and you created your certificates following these steps [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site) it makes a whole seperate store for Certificate you made.

When creating the Client Certificate I just dragged the certificate from its store and moved it into the Personal store(or aka the personal. Ran the command again and it worked!