# Implementing SelfSigned X509 Certificate for WCF Services hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0, iis, ssl

Before jumping into the problem, let me first explain what I am looking for and What is that I have done.

I have created a self-signed X509 Certificates, one for Client and the other for Server.
I have Created a WCF Service and Configured the Web.Config to use the Certificate.
I have even configured the Client Web.Config to make the request based on Certificate based security.
Everything works fine on Self-Hosting.

However When I Deploy the Service on the IIS I have whole bunch of problem, for which I have been looking for solution and nothing worked out.

It would be great if someone can provide the possible solution to this.

Below is the Config File for Server and the Client.

Server (WCF Service) Web.config:

```
   <configuration>
  <appSettings />
  <connectionStrings />
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices/>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceCertificate.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceCertificate.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="https://***.***.**.**:91" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="WCFServiceCertificate.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFServiceCertificate.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="WCfServer" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Client Config:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1387/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior">
        <identity>
          <dns value="WCfServer" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="WcfClient" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

OutPut ScreenShot when browsing the service.

[image]
The browser

Any Help is appriciated...
Thanks in Advance Guys..

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Well I do not get an exception but I am not able to browse the Service. I will attach the screenshot of the response I get when accessed from browser.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you guys for the support.
The only problem was that the certificate was not created under trusted security, it was a normal self signed certificate which was not accepted by the browser.

The problem was solved when the certificate was created under trusted security.
the cofiguration settings holds good.

finally thanks to @Fabrizio for his tremendous help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the client certificates and the server certificate under a trusted certification authority. Both clients and server must trust the certification authority that creates the certificates.
If you have not a CA or money to buy certificates from a public CA, you can set up a working local environment:
 - create a root CA certificate : rootCA
 - install rootCA (pub key) in the trusted root certificates repository on both server and clients
 - create https certificate from rootCA and install it on IIS
 - create client certificates and install them on clients

Starting from a previous question on stackoverflow   [Using makecert for Development SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496658/using-makecert-for-development-ssl)
I wrote a step by step guide:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s0DpnFhwhBamYfwZUGLJokDJPDSzGYO5Ct2hxzq4SA4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio for your helpful links and material.<br> my configuration worked fine on hosting environment even however I realized that the certificate was not accepted by the client machine as it was not under trusted security. except for that everything worked fine. Thank you once again.