# Unable to resolve "unable to get local issuer certificate" using git on Windows with self-signed certificate

Tags: windows, git, curl, ssl-certificate, msysgit

I am using Git on Windows. I installed the msysGit package. My test repository has a self signed certificate at the server. I can access and use the repository using HTTP without problems. Moving to HTTPS gives the error:

> SSL Certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

I have the self signed certificate installed in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities of my Windows 7 - client machine. I can browse to the HTTPS repository URL in Internet Explorer with no error messages.

[This blog post by Philip Kelley](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/phkelley/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store) explained that cURL does not use the client machine's certificate store. I followed the blog post's advice to create a private copy of `curl-ca-bundle.crt` and configure Git to use it. I am sure Git is using my copy. If I rename the copy; Git complains the file is missing.

I pasted in my certificate, as mentioned in the blog post, I still get the message "unable to get local issuer certificate".

I verified that Git was still working by cloning a GitHub Repository via HTTPS.

The only thing I see that's different to the blog post is that my certificate *is* the root - there is no chain to reach it. My certificate originally came from clicking the IIS8 IIS Manager link 'Create Self Signed Certificate'. Maybe that makes a certificate different in some way to what cURL expects.

How can I get Git/cURL to accept the self signed certificate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [configure Git to accept a particular self-signed server certificate for a particular https remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072376/configure-git-to-accept-a-particular-self-signed-server-certificate-for-a-partic)

Comment: Also check whether your local network is permitted to push files to github repository. There may be some firewall or antivirus restriction.

Comment: If anyone faces this error while using Bower, create a .bowerrc file with content `{ "strict-ssl": false }`. Don't thank me, thank this guy: https://stapp.space/fight-with-2/ I've fought with this error for close to 5 hours, straight!!

Comment: Might help someone: I am using gitlab and I face this error if I clone via https. But if I use ssh then it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I get the best solution here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/61608965#61608965

Comment: I was getting this error in Azure Pipelines. You can find the solution at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70952475/1176573).

Comment: For me I was getting this issue when I have installed Git with Homebrew on Linux. After changing Git from Homebrew to apt package, this was fixed.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496738/1264804) to  [Using makecert for Development SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496658/using-makecert-for-development-ssl) fixed this for me.

I do not know why, but the certificate created by the simple 'Create Self Signed Certificate' link in IIS Manager does not do the trick.  I followed the approach in the linked question of creating and installing a self-signed CA Root; then using that to issue a Server Authentication Certificate for my server.  I installed both of them in IIS.

That gets my situation the same as the blog post referenced in the original question.  Once the root certificate was copy/pasted into curl-ca-bundle.crt the git/curl combo were satisfied.

Comment: *"I do not know why, but the certificate created by the simple 'Create Self Signed Certificate' link in IIS Manager does not do the trick..."* - The best I can tell, it creates malformed certificates. There's lots of rules when creating X.509 certificates; the "do the minimum to make it work" no longer works well. Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Comment: This worked for me, but I got temporarily hung up on the "I installed both of them in IIS" part.  To clairfy for others...the server cert is assigned in IIS, and the root CA needs to be imported to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities” via the Windows cert manager utility (certmgr.msc)

Answer (score 925):

The problem is that git by default using the "Linux" crypto backend.

Beginning with Git for Windows 2.14, you can now configure Git to use SChannel, the built-in Windows networking layer as the crypto backend. This means that it will use the Windows certificate storage mechanism and you do not need to explicitly configure the curl CA storage mechanism: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123(v=vs.85).aspx

Just execute:

```
git config --global http.sslbackend schannel
```

That should help.

Using schannel is by now the standard setting when installing git for Windows, also it is recommended to not checkout repositories by SSH anmore if possible, as https is easier to configure and less likely to be blocked by a firewall it means less chance of failure.

Comment: Note however that this solution can make `git config --global http.sslCAInfo <my-server-self-signed-cert.pem>` fail to work.  I configured `http.sslCAInfo` to use a self-signed certificate for my server, and it's the reason (may not be same as OP) that I encountered "SSL Certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" when I do e.g. a `git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode.git`.  Finally I used the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47196562/1323552 (Ben P.P. Tung) to tune my sslCAInfo config specific to my git server to solve it.

Comment: If you are looking way to include a certificate for on-premise github server into the git certstore, follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70952475/1176573).

Comment: This one worked for me, I'm using VS code, company has some VPN software installed guarding the traffic, this solution resolve my issue. Thanks.

Comment: After this command I got another error: "... schannel: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted", because Git repository now holds untrusted certificate. Then I used `git config --global http.sslVerify false`, which is insecure.

Comment: THIS but watch out for productivity firewalls that stop the setting actually changing. In Windows especially, run the Git CMD as admin.

Comment: In Visual studio go to git settings select Git global settings and change the Cryptographic network provider option to Secure Channel

Answer (score 488):

Open Git Bash and run the command if you want to completely disable SSL verification.

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

**Note: This solution opens you to attacks like man-in-the-middle attacks**.
Therefore turn on verification again as soon as possible:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify true
```

Comment: This answer defeats the security of SSL by permitting man-in-the-middle attacks. Other answers already explain how to configure git to trust the specific certificate you need.

Comment: horrible answer indeed, you don't even tell them to turn SSL back on. This is why security vulnerabilities happen.

Comment: If you are using Gitblit then no other option instead of doing sshVerify false.

Comment: To disable TLS/SSL verification for a single git command, use the following command: `git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://domain.com/path/to/git`

Comment: There are several solutions already provided below, and I have already suggested the cons. So it's up to you that what solutions you are are picking to resolve the issue.

Comment: What worked for me was: `git clone <addr of repo> --config http.proxy= --config http.sslVerify=false`

Comment: Leave out `global` to apply the setting per repo for more security.

Comment: To apply this sslVerify=false change, the cmd (or the one you are using) window needs to be restarted.

Comment: This can be a workarround, but never a solution. Also, it is better do not bypass all ssl verification. You can use `git config --local http.sslVerify false`. In this way only one repository is insecure

Comment: This is always the wrong answer. The point of SSL is security. It is enabled by default for a reason.

Comment: Agreed this is always a bad idea. It's a band-aid / temporary workaround at best. Especially if on a corporate network, always work through the problem to ensure appropriate security is being used.

Comment: This is not a wrong or a bad answer.  As long as the risks are documented, it's perfectly legit.  You use at your own risk.  The holier than thou crowd can struggle for the next few hours on this one while the rest of us move on with life.

Answer (score 99):

I had this issue as well.  In my case, I was trying to get a post-receive Git hook to update a working copy on a server with each push.  Tried to follow the instructions in the blog you linked to.  Didn't work for me as well and overriding the settings on a per-user basis didn't seem to work either.

What I ended up having to do was disable SSL verification (as the article mentions) for Git as a whole.  Not the perfect solution, but it'll work until I can figure out a better one.

I edited the Git config text file (with my favorite line-ending neutral app like Notepad++) located at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig

In the [http] block, I added an option to disable sslVerify.  It looked like this when I was done:

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
    sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

That did the trick.

**NOTE:**

- This disables SSL verification and is not recommended as a long term solution.
- You can disable this per-repository which still isn't great, but localizes the setting.
- With the advent of LetsEncrypt.org, it is now fairly simple, automated and free to set up SSL as an alternative to self-signed certs and negates the need to turn off sslVerify.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of SSL.

Comment: you can use the command "git config --global http.sslVerify false" to disable SSL verification

Comment: Thanks for pointing the `sslCAinfo` configuration entry out; but I'm not upvoting the answer since it doesn't make much sense to permanently disable SSL for git system-wide (have you tried to disable it system-wide, then clone, then re-enable it and then disable it in the local git config for the newly cloned repo?).

Comment: For a one-off command, there is no need to change config files: `git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://...`

Comment: @syaz Yes, this is something required when you must work with servers managed by admins who do not know what they are doing and you have to access the repos on that server and port 22 is disabled on all connections, even their own servers that that they otherwise cannot secure, apparently.

Comment: Better fix here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/

Answer (score 75):

**kiddailey** I think was pretty close, however I would not disable ssl verification but rather rather just supply the local certificate:

In the Git config file

```
[http]
    sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

Or via command line:

```
git config --global http.sslCAinfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: On git for windows, this is `git config --global http.sslCAinfo /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: Or for me `git config --global http.sslCAinfo /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: For users on MacPorts, this is `git config --global http.sslCAinfo /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: With Git 2.8 you can use `git config --list --show-origin` to see where the http.sslCAinfo config  is set

Comment: My certificate location on mac is : ~/macports/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt

Comment: I would advise against changing the git cert store. Better approach is to find where the git cert store is using the command `git config --list --show-scope` and later append your certs in that file. Refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70952475/1176573)

Answer (score 64):

I faced this issue as well. And finally got resolved by getting guidance from [this MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exe-s-store.aspx).

**Update**

Actually you need to add the certificate in git's certificates file curl-ca-bundel.cert that resides in Git\bin directory.

**Steps**

1. Open your github page in browser, and click over lock icon in address bar.
2. In the opened little popup up navigate to 'view certificate' link, it will open a popup window.
3. In which navigate to certificates tab (3rd in my case). Select the top node that is root certificate. And press copy certificate button in the bottom and save the file.
4. In file explorer navigate Git\bin directory and open curl-ca-bundle.crt in text editor.
5. Open the exported certificate file (in step 3) in text editor as well.
6. Copy all of the content from exported certificate to the end of curl-ca-bundle.crt, and save.

Finally check the status. **Please note that backup curl-ca-bundle.crt file before editing to remain on safe side.**

Comment: "navigate Git\bin directory and open curl-ca-bundle.crt" There is not curl-ca-bundle.crt in the git\bin!

Comment: @AntonK if it doesn't exist, create one yourself in notepad, and rename it with curl-ca-bundle.crt. Other steps remain same.

Comment: @AntonK It may be called just `ca-bundle.crt` and be located in `mingw64\ssl\certs` or `mingw32\ssl\certs`.

Comment: Used this for Atlassian's SourceTree.  The bundled GIT installation is in %userprofile%\appdata\local\attlassian\sourcetree\git_local. curl-ca-bundle.crt already existed, appended my base64 encoded exported root cert.

Comment: One problem with this answer. When you update git it restores the ca-bundle.crt file to it's original state (i.e. you loose your self signed public cert)

Comment: Link gives a 403.

Answer (score 42):

In case of **github Repositories (or any none-self-signed certs)**, choosing below while installing Git-on-windows, resolved the issue.

[image]

Comment: You seemed to have answered a different question. The OP's question concerned self-signed certificates on Windows clients.

Comment: @jww the question title is a git error message that's shown even if repo is NOT self-signed SSL!

Comment: This got me passed the error, but for me accessing GitHub Enterprise required some key generation and adding of public/private keys.

Comment: If the self signed certifcate has been put into the windows certificates store by a helpful windows admin via a group policy then this answer is also a good one.

Comment: This solution is MUCH better than fiddling with SSL or manually adding certificates. Easy solution that actually works! (I'm a developer, not a system admin. I don't want to be bothered with certificates and stuff)

Comment: If you want to do this after installation, you can use the following command: `git config --global http.sslBackend schannel`

Answer (score 36):

To avoid disabling ssl verification entirely or duplicating / hacking the bundled CA certificate file used by git, you can export **the host's certificate chain into a file**, and make git use it:

```
git config --global http.https://the.host.com/.sslCAInfo c:/users/me/the.host.com.cer
```

If that does not work, you can disable ssl verification **only** for the host:

```
git config --global http.https://the.host.com/.sslVerify false
```

Note : Subjected to possible man in the middle attacks when ssl verification is turned off.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the `--global` option is not necessary: if you omit `--global`, the setting only applies to that particular git repo.

Comment: How about if its my enterprise github? How do I obtain the root and intermediate CA is `.cer` format. I could only get `.p7b` files.

Answer (score 32):

To completely detail out the summary of all the above answers.

### Reason

This problem is occuring because git cannot complete the https handshake with the git server were the repository you are trying to access is present.

### Solution

**Steps to get the certificate from the github server**

1. Open the github you are trying to access in the browser
2. Press on the lock icon in the address bar > click on 'certificate'
3. Go to 'Certification Path' tab > select the top most node in the hierarchy of certificates > click on 'view certificate'
4. Now click on 'Details' and click on 'Copy to File..' > Click 'Next' > Select 'Base 64 encoded X509 (.CER)' > save it to any of your desired path.

**Steps to add the certificate to local git certificate store**

1. Now open the certificate you saved in the notepad and copy the content along with --Begin Certificate-- and --end certificate--
2. To find the path were all the certificates are stored for your git, execute the following command in cmd.

   git config --list
3. Check for the key 'http.sslcainfo', the corresponding value will be path.

> Note: If u can't find the key http.sslcainfo check for Git's default path: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs

4. Now open 'ca-bundle.crt' present in that path.

> Note 1 : open this file administrator mode otherwise you will not be able to save it after update. (Tip - you can use Notepad++ for this
> purpose)
>
> Note 2 : Before modifying this file please keep a backup elsewhere.

5. Now copy the contents of file mentioned in step 1 to the file in step 4 at end file, like how other certificates are placed in ca-bundle.crt.
6. Now open a new terminal and now you should be able to perform operations related to the git server using https.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work behind corporate firewall situations.

Answer (score 25):

I've just had the same issue but using sourcetree on windows Same steps for normal GIT on Windows as well. Following the following steps I was able to solve this issue.

1. Obtain the server certificate tree
   This can be done using chrome.
   Navigate to be server address.
   Click on the padlock icon and view the certificates.
   Export all of the certificate chain as base64 encoded files (PEM) format.
2. Add the certificates to the trust chain of your GIT trust config file
   Run "git config --list".
   find the "http.sslcainfo" configuration this shows where the certificate trust file is located.
   Copy all the certificates into the trust chain file including the "- -BEGIN- -" and the "- -END- -".
3. Make sure you add the entire certificate Chain to the certificates file

This should solve your issue with the self-signed certificates and using GIT.

I tried using the "http.sslcapath" configuration but this did not work. Also if i did not include the whole chain in the certificates file then this would also fail. If anyone has pointers on these please let me know as the above has to be repeated for a new install.

If this is the system GIT then you can use the options in TOOLS -> options
GIt tab to use the system GIT and this then solves the issue in sourcetree as well.

Comment: "if i did not include the whole chain in the certificates file then this would also fail" - I just ran into this problem

Comment: As far as including the whole chain, I have two certs above the github cert. Do I include them in order as root->next cert->github cert in the sslcainfo.crt file?

Comment: I was able to access git repo packages by just adding the root cert.

Comment: For future readers. No idea if it matters, but I put the "root" (topmost) cert at the END of the (http.sslcainfo) file.  And then as I went away from the root cert in the chain, I put that cert above the previous entry of the (http.sslcainfo) file.

Answer (score 19):

When using Windows, the problem resides that git by default uses the "Linux" crypto backend. Starting with Git for Windows 2.14, you can configure Git to use SChannel, the built-in Windows networking layer as the crypto backend. To do that, just run the following command in the GIT client:

```
git config --global http.sslbackend schannel
```

This means that it will use the Windows certificate storage mechanism and you don't need to explicitly configure the curl CA storage (http.sslCAInfo) mechanism.

Comment: worked as a charm!

Comment: Yep, this works great.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

I have had this issue before, and solve it using the following config.

`[http "https://your.domain"]
   sslCAInfo=/path/to/your/domain/priviate-certificate`

Since git 2.3.1, you can put `https://your.domain` after http to indicate the following certificate is only for it.

Comment: This is the simpliest & most precise solution I found, if you also configured `git config --global http.sslCAInfo <your-server-self-signed-cert.pem>` before (Hence causing the "unable to get local issuer certificate" error)

Answer (score 12):

Jan 2021 - Got around this in VS2019 by setting Menu > Git > Settings > Git Global Settings > Cryptographic Network Provider > [Secure Channel] instead of [OpenSSL]

[Git SSL certificate problem unable to get local issuer certificate (fix)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9frW.png)

PS: Didn't need to set --global or --local http.sslVerify false. I was cloning an Azure DevOps repo which wasn't using any self signed certs.. This seems like an issue with either VS2019 or Git for Windows.. They need to fix it !!

Comment: The command line equivalent (for non VS2019 etc) is : git config --global http.sslBackend schannel

Answer (score 11):

In my case, as I have installed the [ConEmu Terminal](https://conemu.github.io/en/) for Window 7, it creates the `ca-bundle` during installation at `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs`.

Thus, I have to run the following commands on terminal to make it work:

```
$ git config --global http.sslbackend schannel
$ git config --global http.sslcainfo /mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Hence, my `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig` contains the following:

```
[http]
    sslBackend = schannel
    sslCAinfo = /mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Also, I chose same option as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows/45695638#45695638) when installing the Git.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 10):

I have also recently faced this issue, and you get this issue usually when you are behind some corporate firewall, and then git cannot complete the https handshake with the git repository that you are trying to access. One of the way to solve it, is to use this command:

```
git config --global http.sslverify false
```

But as others have said this pretty much disables the ssl verification. The only secure way is to get the SSL certificate and add it locally to your Git folder, specifically in the file `ca-bundle.crt`.

One way to solve it, is to use the package [`pcer`](https://github.com/PeterHdd/pcer), to install it you need to do the following:

```
npm i -g pcer
```

Then you execute the following:

```
pcer alias git "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt"
```

This would make `git` point to the above path, and then you can `fetch` the certificate by doing the following:

```
pcer fetch github.com -l git
```

Then you can perform git clone and it would work normally. For example:

[image]

For more information:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcer

https://github.com/PeterHdd/pcer

*Note, I'm the owner of this package*

Answer (score 4):

One thing that messed me up was the format of the path (on my Windows PC).  I originally had this:

```
git config --global http.sslCAInfo C:\certs\cacert.pem
```

But that failed with the "unable to get local issuer certificate" error.

What finally worked was this:

```
git config --global http.sslCAInfo "C:\\certs\\cacert.pem"
```

Answer (score 4):

solved my problem
git config --global http.sslBackend schannel

Answer (score 3):

1. **Download certificate from this link:**
   https://github.com/bagder/ca-bundle
2. **Add it to** `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`

Then try something like: `git clone https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started.git`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to use **different certificates** for **different git repositories**.

Follow steps below (If you have a certificate of your repository, you can read from **step 5**)

1. Go to remote repository's site. Ex: github.com, bitbucket.org, tfs.example...
2. Click **Lock** icon on the upper left side and click **Certificate**.
3. Go to **Certification Path** tab and double click to **.. Root Certificate**
4. Go to **Details** tab and click **Copy to file**.
5. Export/Copy certificate to wherever you want. Ex: C:\certs\example.cer
6. Open git bash at your local repository folder and type:

   `$ git config http.sslCAInfo "C:\certs\example.cer"`

Now you can use different certificates for each repository.

Remember, calling with the `--global` parameter will also change the certificates of git repositories in other folders, so **you should not use** the `--global` parameter when executing this command.

Answer (score 3):

```
git config --global http.sslbackend secure-transport
```

(had to do that after update to Big Sюr)

Comment: after updating to Mac Big Sur, we too got `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`. This fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

To fix the especific error [SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53210531/ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-in-git)

I had the same issue with Let's Encrypt certificates .

An web site with https we just to need :

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

but git pull says :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://example.com/git/demo.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

To fix it, we need also add:

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

git config --global http.sslVerify false

Comment: this worked for me and missing is you need to turn verification as mentioned in the below answers

Comment: Hello, man in the middle... DON'T USE THIS! Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34049063/161979 .

Answer (score 2):

Download and install local certificate. Probably it is published at your company site. For instance, *.cer file.

1. Right click it and select `Install Certificate`. 'Certificate Inport Wizard' will appear. Select `Local Machine`. Press `Next`, confirm.
2. Select `Place all certificates in the following store`, press `Browse` and select `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`, `OK`, `Finish`.

[image]

Also you can check if other applications can fetch, pull or push data. For instance, in `Android Studio` or probably `IDEA` you should select in `Settings` this checkbox: `Use credential helper`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem from Azure DevOps (Visual Studio). Finally I've decided to clone my repo using **SSH** protocol because of i've prefered it instead of disabling SSL verification.

You only need to generate a SSH Key, you can do it so... [SSH documentation](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/)

```
ssh-keygen
```

And then, import your public key on yout git host (like Azure Devops, Github, Bitbucket, Gitlab, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error occur when using visual studio. This occurs when you have the Cryptographic Network provider settings set to OpenSSL in the Visual Studio Options window. When I changed the setting to Secure Channel it solved it for me. This setting must have been set for me when I upgraded my VS.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I opened cmd line and ran following command. and pulled again.

> git config --global http.sslVerify false

Comment: This disables a lot of security. It should be marked as a workaround and it is not specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when trying to "clone" the project.  One work-around is to just use the "download as zip" on the webpage, which, for me, achieved what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

#### Error

> push failed
> fatal: unable to access
> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

#### Reason

After committing files on a local machine, the "push fail" error can occur when the local Git connection parameters are outdated (e.g. HTTP change to HTTPS).

#### Solution

1. Open the `.git` folder in the root of the local directory
2. Open the `config` file in a code editor or text editor (VS Code, Notepad, Textpad)
3. **Replace HTTP links** inside the file with the latest **HTTPS** or **SSH** link available from the web page of the appropriate Git repo (clone button)
   Examples:

   ```
   url = http://git.[host]/[group/project/repo_name]     (actual path)
   ```

   replace it with either

   ```
   url = ssh://git@git.[host]:/[group/project/repo_name] (new path SSH)
   url = https://git.[host]/[group/project/repo_name]    (new path HTTPS)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by adding below entry in ${HOME}/.gitconfig file

[remote "origin"]

proxy=

In most case it will happen when proxy enabled in your machine so above mentioned entry will fix this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might have a DNS issue and not a certificate issue, so before you disable SSL verification in your Git shell you should rule out a DNS problem. Cases such as these have been mentioned in Q&A forums such as [https-issues-possibly-related-to-dns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/86776/34random34-https-issues-possibly-related-to-dns-se.html?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=oldest). If you are using WSL on Windows as your terminal, then you can try running `sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf` and then issue the git commands to see if that makes a difference. This does not seem to be a permanent DNS fix (lasting only the lifetime of your terminal session), but it could help you determine whether it is a DNS issue and not a certificate issue. You could also [check this document on configuring your network to use a public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using). Again, this is only to help you determine if your DNS settings might need adjusting in order to help resolve the certificate issues.

Answer (score -1):

This might help some who come across this error.  If you are working across a VPN and it becomes disconnected, you can also get this error.  The simple fix is to reconnect your VPN.

Answer (score -3):

Use Github Desktop.
It avoids all this mess. No configuration required, no re-settings, no SSL issues.

In fact Github Desktop can help you work with multiple enterprise and cloud versions at the same time.

Answer (score -4):

I tried following and it worked ✅

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: This disables a lot of security. It should be marked as a workaround and it is not specific enough.

Answer (score -7):

Use this command before to run composer update/install:

```
git config --global http.sslverify false
```