# Deploy a NodeJS app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've followed the getting started guide to deploy a `nodejs` application to heroku:

[I reached to this stage in the tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app)

When I try to write the command:

```
heroku create
```

It gives me this error:

`UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY: unable to get local issuer certificate`

What can be the problem?

Comment: have u tried `heroku login` first?

Comment: yes, I did try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have a web filter on my internet, A content filter and it was blocking the command

```
heroku create
```

from going through.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

Edit Git config text file (with my favorite line-ending neutral app like Notepad++) located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig
```

In the [http] block, add an option to disable sslVerify. It looked like this when I was done:

```
[http]
sslVerify = false
sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

The answer is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following line:

npm config set strict-ssl false

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10:

Go to System variable (Windows logo key > type: "environment variables" > click Environment Variables button)

Check/Set Variable SSL_CERT_DIR=YourCetrFolder

[image]

Certificate folder Example:

[image]