# Team Foundation Server 2017 & VS 2017 - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, certificate

i have read the following question: [Unable to resolve "unable to get local issuer certificate" using git on Windows with self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows#)

I have the same error. Context is Visual Studio 2017 with the Team Foundation Server 2017 (using Git).
Our service user and admin account is able to clone the repository, but our ordinary users not. It seems to be a problem of user authorities? I have tried several approaches, but can't find any further clue.

Any suggestions so far?

Edit: it is not a duplicate. The mentioned thread describes a different problem. Service user from the tfs and admin CAN clone the repository (on the same pc), but a normal user can not. Both mentioned users are also admin of the tfs server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to resolve "unable to get local issuer certificate" using git on Windows with self-signed certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows)

Comment: Unfortunately not, see edit.

Comment: Does the "service user" means those users who use domain account to clone or other account? And the "ordinary users" means those users use local account and these account not at the Administrator group of your TFS server computer?

Comment: Please try to Delete the credential of your account in Credential Manager and clone again in VS 2017.

Comment: The TFS runs under a service-user. This user has also local admin rights of the server. We have additional admin-users as well for server maintenance which have also those rights. Our software developer accounts from our domain are not able to clone. I will try to do this credential method hopefully by wednesday.

Comment: Is there any feedback, did you delete the credentials and try again. From the comment you posted above? Only adminintrators could clone, the developers couldn't clone. So Did you give those develop account enough [permissions](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AopgZUVNxLwJgUNXsV2VuzyWFIE7)? You need to make sure these permission are set to **Allow**.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This was not the solution, but I have overlooked an important case. It is not enough to add the certificate-blocks of the tfs on-site and of the root domain to the github certificate repository. Additionally, I had to set the local cert-file like it is mentioned in thread above: git config --global http.sslCAinfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt