# How to configure Git to use Windows' System Certificate Store?

Tags: git

I want to configure Git to use Windows' System Certificate Store, where my self-signed root certicates are stored.

However, I can only find documentation on how to make Git trust a given `.crt` CA bundle.

Is it possible to make Git trust Windows' System Certificate Store?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to resolve "unable to get local issuer certificate" using git on Windows with self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows)

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon - It doesn't say how to tell git: "use Windows' system certificate store instead of your own."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064542/11239008

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon - Thank you!!!  It solved my problem 