# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate when push to remote repository

Tags: php, git

I want to push my local to remote repository, but I get this error in GIT

```
$ git push origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.kgmedia.id/es/portal/home.git/': SSL 
certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I don't know what's wrong with it, the last time I push to remote repository this doesn't appear

Comment: Are you on Windows ?

Comment: yes, I am using widows

Comment: What you likely did is that you installed git with the linux crypto backend. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064542/6086785). If the following command solves the issue: `git config --global http.sslbackend schannel` I suggest re-installing git and making sure you select the Windows native crypto layer during the installation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this as a workaround:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: Please do not disable SSL verification. It renders the whole thing pointless. This should not be a solution, even if it works.

Comment: I know it is not good to do this, I just provided a workaround right now, I was looking for an actual solution.