# Azure Devops OnPremise, fatal: Authentication failed for when cloning Git repo

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

Using OnPremise Azure Devops 2019 server I am trying to programmatically clone a git repository by calling the following git command inside a ProcessInfo:

```
clone https://{username}:{PATTOKEN}@{DEVOPSSERVERDOMAIN}/{TEAMPROJECT}/_git/{PROJECT}
```

Here is the c# code:

```
  var gitInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        FileName = pathToGitExe
                    };

Process gitProcess = new Process();
                gitInfo.Arguments = theCloneCommand
                gitInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingFolder;
                gitProcess.StartInfo = gitInfo;
                gitProcess.Start();
```

But I keep getting the error

```
Cloning into 'PROJECT'...
fatal: Authentication failed for '{DEVOPSSERVERDOMAIN}/{TEAMPROJECT}/_git/{PROJECT}'
```

Is the PAT not correctly used? Any suggestions

Comment: Hi did you get a chance to tried adding the extra header to git command as below answer mentioned, how did it go?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT thanks! I am currently testing it, I will let you know today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you should try the clone without `username`.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/2455

```
https://<PAT>@mydomain.visualstudio.com/myproject/_git/myrepo
```

Comment: Hi @AlexAIT I tried your suggestion but I got the error fatal: unable to access 'UrlToProject': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Feels like a step forward to me. This issue usually points to a self-signed certificate which cannot be validated. There are workarounds like disabling validation in this case, see as an example: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-816521128.html The is much more information online if you look for this error specifically.

Comment: I ended up setting the sChannel property like suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows so no need for PAT
just invoke the command git config --global http.sslbackend schannel

Answer (score 1):

If you enable IIS Basic Authentication for Azure Devops server, PATs aren't valid. See [Enabling IIS Basic Authentication invalidates using Personal Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops).

As it is said in above document, you need to add an extra header which includes a base 64 encoding of "user:PAT" to the Git requests:

`git -c http.extraheader='Authorization: Basic [base 64 encoding of "user:PAT"]' ls-remote http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/projectName`

You can  Base64-encode the username and PAT using below poweshell script:

```
$MyPat = 'yourPAT'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("user:$MyPat"))
```

Or with C# code:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "user", personalaccesstoken))));
```

For more information, See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat).

You can try using your userName and password instead of PAT as authentication:

```
git clone https://{username}:{password}@{DEVOPSSERVERDOMAIN}/{TEAMPROJECT}/_git/{PROJECT}
#if your password or username contain @ replace it with %40
```

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT I tried it with the http.extraheader, so the gitInfo.Arguments = "-c http.extraheader='Authorization:Basic TheEncodedPAT' ls-remote TheServerUrl"
but I am getting the following error
git: 'TheEncodedPAT'' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: Probably an issue with using the processinfo arguments and string attributes