# Clone of Gitlab repository through azure pipeline showing SSL error

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have been doing a git clone of a repository in Gitlab through an azure pipeline and it showed the following error:

```
2020-08-13T11:23:42.2930076Z ##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 6.913 seconds before retry.
2020-08-13T11:23:49.1339276Z ##[command]git fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=2 origin
2020-08-13T11:23:49.3214993Z fatal: unable to access 'https://*****/gitlab/****/web.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: This problem usually occurs on `self-hosted agents`. If you use this kind of agnet, you can refer to the following answer to solve the problem. If not, you share your `agent type` `gitlab verification method`.

Comment: I am using agent pull "Azure Pipelines".

Comment: Till now i am unable to clone from gitlab ....my main challenge how to handle "git config --global http.sslVerify false" this command in azure devops pipeline

Comment: In Azure Pipeline, you could add a `Command line ` task to run this script. Could you please help me check if this issue exists in the Checkout step? If yes, this method may not be suitable. By the way , I tested with `Azure Pipelines ->vs2017-win2016` and it could work.

Comment: @RakeshKumarRoutray did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer

From the error log, this problem often occurs when using `self-hosted agent`.

This error occurs when a self-signed certificate cannot be verified.

You could running the following script on your local machine to  turn off `sslVerify` .

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

On the other hand , you could configure the  git certificate.

1. Add Enterprise CA certificate to `git config –global http.sslCAInfo.`
2. Tell Git where to find the CA bundle by running:

   `git config --system http.sslCAPath / absolute / path / to / git / certificates`

or copying the CA bundle to the /bin directory and adding the following to the gitconfig file:

```
sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

3. Restart the agent.

Try following the tutorial which mentioned in  [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/phkelley/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store).

Here is a ticket about [Unable to resolve “unable to get local issuer certificate” using git on Windows with self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows)

Comment: but how to add this ssl false command in azure devops pipeline ? Could you please help me ?

Comment: @RakeshKumarRoutray  if you have a fixed machine, run this command once in your machine and it will stay. If the VM is a clean one each time, you can add a task "Command Line" before the git clone to disable the SSL