# curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Tags: android, ssl, curl, certificate, open-source

I am trying to install an opensource project(https://github.com/oppia/oppia-android) on my PC(windows 11), I have done all the three steps mentioned in this installation Guide https://github.com/oppia/oppia-android/wiki#installation, but I am getting this error(see image) when I try to run this command 'bash scripts/setup.sh' on git bash. What can I do to solve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Fpj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this in git bash:

```
git config --global http.sslbackend schannel
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064542/9972209)