# Issue with pulling/pushing code to github

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

While trying to pull code from Github, it throws this error

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Background - Running on windows, corporate laptop but accessing git doesn't require a firewall or specific certificates.

Tested solutions are in this link, but so far nothing has worked. -
[Unable to resolve "unable to get local issuer certificate" using git on Windows with self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885449/unable-to-resolve-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-using-git-on-windows)

After changing `sslBackend` from `openssl` to `schannel`, I was getting a different error

```
schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

Tried setting

```
git config --global http.schannelCheckRevoke false;
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

but the error code hasn't been resolved or changed.

Here is my `.gitconfig` for reference.

```
[diff "astextplain"]    
    textconv = astextplain 
[filter "lfs"]  
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f     
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f   
    process = git-lfs filter-process    
    required = true 
[http]  
    sslBackend = openssl    
    sslCAInfo = C:/Users/%userprofile%/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt 
[core]  
    autocrlf = true     
    fscache = true  
    symlinks = false 
[pull]  
    rebase = false 
[credential]    
    helper = manager 
[credential "https://dev.azure.com"]    
    useHttpPath = true 
[init]  
    defaultBranch = master
```

Comment: maybe [this can help](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-816521128.html)