# How to authencticate the encrypt password with input password value?

Tags: encryption, asp.net-web-api

Here we call webapi service from mobile application to authenticate the userid and encrypted password in database.
So to authenticate I encrypt the input password and compare with database password?

Another question: Is it correct what I am doing?
Or is it a better way to decrypt the database password value and check with input value. If second way is better, how can I do that?

Below is my code:

```
  using (LoginServiceEntities context = new LoginServiceEntities())
        {
            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
            var encrypass = crypto.Compute(Password);
            var user = (from u in context.user_master
                        where String.Compare(u.UserID, UserID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                              && u.Password== encrypass
                        select u).FirstOrDefault();

            return user != null;
    }
```

Comment: Background material: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Answer (score 0):

Password in database should not be decrypted.
What you are doing is correct. Just compare the encrypted password in database with the encrypted input

Comment: ok when I encrypt the password than here encrypt value and db encrypted values different I update my code please check once

Comment: I am storing the value in db using below code( var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
                        var encrypass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);
             hash salt to how to encrypt input value using hash+salt

Comment: you should use the same method to encrypt both of them, why should you use different method of encryption?

Comment: yes my doubt is how to do that? could you please help me here?

Comment: you are using  var cipherText = Encript.Encrypt(Password); to encrypt the input password, so just use the same method  Encript.Encrypt(passwordToSaveToDb) to save the password to db. And next time when you compare the password, it will be same.

Comment: when I register with password this is encrypt value 'jlS6RC+Ie2xqdOCzI2lXGCgnts3ipWwJmnoUNIcy+Wgjc5B9qCU2ngC8D/deZvI714oURhLlMdOti2Rz9Bz8oQ==' but when I encrypt the input Qlujqgr9l0qYAFDwC/ABvQJaZXg0hpA0k9zDSNcuD+zJrUKCx0kUnZ2WHgoVQ9CAySXxtBkZwdF1qJF7lLR5aA==

Comment: so comparison is not happping

Comment: I modified my code as above than also it's not working