# ssl wcf make certificate available on another computer

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I followed:
http://www.remondo.net/how-to-install-test-certificate-for-wcf-ssl-transport/
http://www.remondo.net/using-ssl-transport-security-wcf-basichttpbinding/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24027/SSL-with-Self-hosted-WCF-Service
[Using makecert for Development SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496658/using-makecert-for-development-ssl)

and was able to create SSL self hosted wcf service on my computer.
it works great.

i tried to put my client on another computer. and connect to my computer and it resulted a failure.

I created a pfx file

I tried to install pfx/cer/pvk on the client machine but nothing helps.

tried to lower firewall/antivirus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to export a pfx file, you only need to export the public key of the self-signed certificate and install that in the trusted root certificates store on the other computer running your client application.

To do this, export the self-signed certificate as a .cer file. Copy this file to the other computer and import it. When you import it, make sure to place it in the Trusted Root Certificates store.

Also, include the exception information in your question.